# php slim passing arguments for named functions

Tags: php, rest, slim

I'm using PHP slim framework version 2. In their documentation, they have not specified how to pass argument to call
How to receive arguments in the function.

`$app->get('/books/{id}', 'getBook')`

```
function getBook($id){
var_dump($id);
    die('there');

}
```

but it gives me an error of either not found or

```
All Route middleware must be callable
```

Answer (score 0):

> @owaishanif786 i don't know this way ($app->get('/books/{id}', 'getBook'))
>   that you used in your question but if i want to call a function in
>   slim framework 2 then i just do it like below please check it:

```
$app->get('/total', function() use($app){
        test(2);
    });

    function test($id){
        echo "yes you were right $id";
    }
```

now just call /total api your function test() with argument $id will call

Answer (score 0):

As of [Slim v3](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html)

```
$app->get('/books/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // $args['id']
});
```